# How do I view all S3 bucket access events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to see all S3 bucket access events, including the web interface and API. But I'm an absolute newbie to AWS. Are there any clear and step-by-step instructions for such a case?

I tried to create an AWS Cloud Trail in the same region, but I didn't see the events I needed. All the events there were more like internal AWS service events. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You'd either need to [Enable CloudTrail event logging for S3 buckets and objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-cloudtrail-logging-for-s3.html) or use Access Logging: [Logging requests using server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I understand correctly that I won't be able to find events BEFORE logging is enabled?

Comment: Correct. Access Logs only start when you activate them, and CloudTrail won't capture object-level events until you active it.